# How to perform a task immediately on logon

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

I would like to know how it is possible to perform a task directly after the explorer process is started. My goal is to process some tasks directly after login on Windows 8, as the "Run" entry in the registry is not immediately executed.

Comment: So you need something to run before the `Run` registry key is loaded, but after Explorer is started. I think you'll get better help if you can explain why you need this bizarre requirement. What's wrong with `Run`?

Comment: the problem with `Run` is that it is executed approx. 10 secs after the start screen is shown, but I need immediate execution.

Comment: What about registering as a service?

Comment: Services run in Session 0, but the tasks I want to process must run in user mode

Comment: A service can spawn processes in user sessions via `CreateProcessAsUser()`, and can receive user login/logout notifications.

Comment: Create a logon-triggered scheduled task. Note of course that this is slowing down boot just for you, so it's a kind of selfish thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [userinit registry key](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939862.aspx), it is the first process to run. I get to the DLL part later.

Rigth after Winlogon gets a token for the user (when that user is authenticated) it lauch all the processes listed un the userinit key, in the order they are listed.

But beware : your process must exit after a few seconds, or else Windows will think that there is a problem with the creation of your desktop, and it will replace your desktop with a default desktop. To test, change the userinit registry key to

```
notepad.exe,userinit.exe
```

You can get around this limitation by making your process relaunch itself at first launch. For example, when `myprocess.exe` is run :

```
If there is no command line
    get the process name and path (with GetModuleFileName, fyi)
    start the process again with /go as a parameter
    exit
```

Now, your original question mentions loading a DLL, and all I talk about is about process. Calling rundll32 on your dll will load it and calling an function on it. From your answers to comments, it looks like using a process is also OK.

Comment: Thank you very much! UserInit is the solution. In my case, a process is also possible, so I didn't use the DLL.

Comment: Note that tampering with UserInit may cause your application to be flagged as malware.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a shell extension which will be loaded into Explorer right away.

Small word of caution: in all situations like this there is a race of "But I want *my* application to be first!" Except everyone wants the same thing, so in effect there's no generalized solution to the problem when talking about a platform like Windows. But if you are more specific about why it's so important that you run before other apps, it would be easier to help. For example Skype runs at startup, and there's no problem that it starts up slightly delayed. It's expected when the system is trying to do 100 things at the same time. Similar scenario is explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).

Comment: Shell Extension sounds good, but how do I make it load on startup? On the internet I only found an example of an extension that registeres a context menu handler.

Comment: I also found something called "Shell Delay Load Object", but I don't know how to register this

Comment: [Here is a list of extension types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer#Extensibility); I am not sure the best one to use but I would start with a column or property handler for the desktop folder.

Comment: But do you know something to "Shell Delay Load Objects"